# Permissions problem using SyncToy to synchronize ClearCase with SharePoint 3.0

Tags: sharepoint-2007, integration, clearcase

So I am trying to setup a simple one way synch from a dynamic ClearCase view over to a MOSS document library. I'm using SyncToy 1.4 as my sync tool and it seems to work fine when it's copying new documents from ClearCase to SharePoint but it's throwing an error when I try to overwrite a file with a new version or try to delete an existing file in SharePoint  because it's deleted in ClearCase.  I'm using the "Echo" sync setting so SharePoint  should always mirror changes in ClearCase.

I've created a custom active directory user for this process and have given that user Full Control on the SharePoint  document library and can manually do these edits/deletes from the explorer view of the doc library when I'm logged into a server as that "sync user" however when I run the synctoy it fails saying the document in SharePoint is "read-only".  My questions is shouldn't synctoy be running as that "sync user" and shouldn't it behave the same as when I manually manipulate the documents in SharePoint in explorer view as that "sync user"?

Answer (score 0):

Is this similar to [Office 2003 and 2007 Office documents open read-only in Internet Explorer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/870853), where SharePoint might considering synctoy access to its files as "browsing access" (always opened as [read-only](http://spsstuff.blogspot.com/2006/07/office-2003-documents-open-in-read.html)) ?

If not, the trick is to make sure your synctoy process does run as "sync user".

Using ClearCase on a regular basis, I do not see any side-effect with having for a source repository a dynamic view.

According to [Managing Data in Windows SharePoint / Updating Child Content Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms442695.aspx),

> If you attempt to perform a push-down operation on a child content type that is marked as read-only, the push-down operation fails unless you set the parent content type to be read/write as part of the push-down operation.

Meaning: you might want to check the rights associated with the parent directory (in Sharepoint) containing the file you try to delete.